# Connecting to iPhone hotspot with 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, iphone

My issue seems to be different from those in the many other threads that I've read.

I have a Lenovo G50 laptop with 16.04 LTS installed. I dual-boot with Windows 10, but I haven't used that in months.

I'm attempting to use <1 yr. old iPhone SE as a personal hotspot, but I cannot seem to get WiFi and Bluetooth working.

- via WiFi, it connects on *maybe* 1 out of every 10 bootups. On the rare occasions when it connects automatically, the connection remains stable throughout that session's usage. Even through sleep, IIRC.

  - When it does NOT connect, then not only does my network name NOT DISPLAY AT ALL in the `nm` list, but when I try to connect to it via "Hidden Networks", the "antenna" icon will cycle through, but result in "Disconnected: you are offline". No amount of, or variation on re-cycling through enabling/disabling networking or wifi on the laptop, nor closing and restarting connection settings on the iPhone, will display the network name or establish any connection.
- via Bluetooth, the network name will display and the connection will work for maybe 10-15 minutes, then go through a series of drops which eventually cannot be re-established. Time to use the iPhone cable!

---

`lshw -c network`:

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 01
       serial: d0:53:49:05:79:17
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.13.0-45-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:40 memory:f0b00000-f0b7ffff memory:f0b80000-f0b8ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 68:f7:28:46:eb:65
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:35 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0a04000-f0a04fff memory:f0a00000-f0a03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1.1
       logical name: enp0s18u1u1c4i2
       serial: c6:61:8b:3a:86:f0
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth ip=172.20.10.3 link=yes multicast=yes
```

`rfkill`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

FWIW nothing shows in the "Additional drivers" tab of System Settings.

Can someone help me dial in a few fixes for this ongoing issue? Thank you.

Comment: Just to confirm, the wireless connection is fine when connecting to any other access point?

Comment: G Trawo, thanks for writing. Yes, it was fine when connecting to a home network via a wireless router some time ago, but I've been away from there for a few weeks now, and *have* accepted some auto upgrades in the interim, if that matters. (Had also meant to mention that I see many nearby network choices in the NM list, but as explained, only rarely do I see my *own* from the iPhone.)

Comment: Oh, and at some point I re-set the "powersave" to either 3 or 0, I cannot recall.

Comment: Could you try connecting to another WiFi hotspot, possibly at a coffee shop near you? If you have similar issues there, then there may be something wrong in Ubuntu. Otherwise, I would point at your phone as the source of your issues.